# asyncio wait until complete task children

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

In asyncio I want to write code to create a task for example called `something`, which is `something`; Creates other new tasks. When the tasks created by `something` are completed, I want the `complete all tasks` sentence to be printed.

**Output I want:**

> *start tasks*
>     *# before and after ...*
>     *complete
> all tasks*

**Code:**

```
async def st(n):
    print('before ', n)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('after ', n)

async def tt(n):
    for i in range(n):
        asyncio.create_task(st(n))

async def main():
    print('start tasks ...')
    loop = asyncio.create_task(tt(3),name='something')
    await loop
    print('complete all tasks')


asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *wait* for something to happen in `asyncio`, that's generally a clue you need to use the `await` command. Calling `asyncio.create_task` doesn't actually cause a task to run; tasks only run when another task yields control by calling `await`.

Assuming that you want the `st()` tasks to run concurrently, something like this would work:

```
import asyncio


async def st(n):
    print("before ", n)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("after ", n)


async def tt(n):
    tasks = []
    for i in range(n):
        tasks.append(st(i))

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


async def main():
    print("start tasks ...")
    await tt(3)
    print("complete all tasks")


asyncio.run(main())
```

In `tt()`, we append each new coroutine to the `tasks` list, and then use [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) to execute the tasks concurrently.

You'll note that we never need to call `asyncio.create_task` here: `asyncio.gather` takes care executing things for us, and in `main` we're only running a single coroutine so we can just `await` on it directly.

Running the above code results in output like this:

```
start tasks ...
before  0
before  1
before  2
after  0
after  1
after  2
complete all tasks
```

Comment: I use this code for telegram robot
maybe I wana cancel the "something" task. can I cancel it when use await?

Comment: Did this answer solve the issue you described in your question? If so, please accept this one and post the above comment as a new question. If this does not resolve the problem you were asking about, please let me know and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Yes, you answered the question I asked. Thank you
But I think I did not write the whole question. Because I want something else. Should I edit the same question or should I ask a new one?